# помогите какую ошибку дает не понимаю сам?

Tags: java, android

Ошибка такая:

```
Error:(13, 8) error: Main is not abstract and does not override abstract method onViewDetachedFromWindow(View) in OnAttachStateChangeListener
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

код

```
package com.example.myapplication77;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public  class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnAttachStateChangeListener{
    private Button btnAdd, btnsub, btndivide, btnmul;
    private TextView tvresult;
    private EditText etfirst, etsecond;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btndivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
        btnsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
        btnmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
        etfirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstNumber);
        etsecond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSecondNumber);
        tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btnsub.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btndivide.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btnmul.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String num1 = etfirst.getText().toString();
        String num2 = etsecond.getText().toString();
        // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                int addition = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
                break;
            case R.id.btnSubtract:
                int subtraction = Integer.parseInt(num1) - Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(subtraction));
                break;
            case R.id.btnDivide:
                try {
                    int division = Integer.parseInt(num1) / Integer.parseInt(num2);
                    tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(division));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    tvresult.setText(String.valueOf("Cannot Divide"));
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.btnMultiply:
                int multiply = Integer.parseInt(num1) * Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(multiply));
                break;
        }  } }
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

В ошибке сообщается о то что вы не унаследовали метод `onViewDetachedFromWindow(View)` из интерфейса `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener`.

Всё что вам нужно, так это унаследовать данный метод если его реализация вам необходима.

```
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view){
    // ваш функционал
}
```

Или же удалить сигнатуру реализации заменив строку:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
```

на данную:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: не роботает все ровно

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы объявили вашу активити реализующей интерфейс `OnAttachStateChangeListener` но не реализовали его в активити, и даже не объявили актвити абстрактной. Вам надо или удалить этот интерфейс или реализовать его. В любом случае нужное вам действие можно вызвать путём нажатия `alt+enter` если курсор на имени интерфейса/актвити находится

Comment: `alt + enter`  - хоткей недоступен на MacOS

Comment: @zTrap, на моём рабочем работает. Правда, может, это таки `cmd+enter`

Comment: это я сам знаю Спасибо